# Max upload size for ASP.MVC CORE website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I set maximum upload size for an `ASP.NET CORE` application?

In the past I was able to set it in `web.config` file like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS? If yes, did you try to put this into your web.config to see if it works?

Comment: What kind of upload is it? There's only a built in limit for Forms and multipart. https://github.com/aspnet/Performance/blob/2a1621d2c5dc1ab1d2ed280866f09cc7e5a81589/testapp/MultipartPOST/MultipartPOST/Startup.cs#L22

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to do that:

1.Using application wise settings - in the > **configure services** method.

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800;
});
```

2.Using RequestFormSizeLimit attribute - for specific actions. - It is not yet available in official package 
[Unofficial](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.FileUpload/Filters/RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute.cs)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the max limit for multipart uploads in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800;

    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

You can also configure the `MaxRequestBufferSize` by using `services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>`, but it looks like this is [going to be deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1027) in the next release.