# .net Core 2.0 File Upload Size Limit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble with uploading large files in a .net core 2.0 MVC web app.

I have seen articles, such as this one, which shows how to increase the file size limit in .net core 2.0:
[Increase upload request length limit in Kestrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738364/increase-upload-request-length-limit-in-kestrel?rq=1)

So, following the example I have tried both options.  I currently have this in my Program.cs:

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options => options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null)
            .Build();
```

... and my ajax file upload method on the controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1_074_790_400)]
    [Route("api/article/uploadfile/{mediaType}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(string mediaType)
```

I'm access the uploaded files using `Request.Form.Files`

The javascript on the view looks like this:

```
$('#upload-videos').change(function () {
    var files = $("#upload-videos").get(0).files;
    uploadMedia(false, files);
})

function uploadMedia(isPhoto, files) {
    var type;
    if (isPhoto) {
        type = "i";
    }
    else {
        type = "v";
    }

    var data = new FormData();
    if (files.length > 0) {
        for (idx = 0; idx < files.length; idx++) {
                data.append("fileImage" + idx, files[idx]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/article/uploadfile/" + type,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (jsonData) {
                refreshUploadedImages(jsonData, isPhoto);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, even with the changes to increase the upload limit in place, I am get the response:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

If I put a break-point on the first line of the controller method it never hits it so it doesn't appear to be a problem with this code.

Everything works fine with small files size but when I try to upload a file which is 538,286 KB in size it will fail.

Can anyone help with this?

Update:
For further information, the problem seems to occur when the upload file size is somewhere between 122,211 KB and 137,840 KB regardless of any RequestSizeLimit settings, and it errors consistently.

Update 2:
I've just updated all .net core and all .net core nuget packages to 2.1 but the problem still exists.

Comment: There should be a `413` and not `500` if the web server cannot handle the file because it is too big.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, this has lead me to believe that the file size is not the problem. However, it still only occurs on large files.

Answer (score 10):

To help anyone else with the same problem I have found the answer here:
[Max upload size for ASP.MVC CORE website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264474/max-upload-size-for-asp-mvc-core-website)

It turns out that you need to remove the body length limit like this:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1_074_790_400);
```

`FormOptions` can be found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` namespace.

Comment: Is the `MaxRequestBodySize` to be set separately?

Comment: Yes, you will still need to set this if you want to allow large downloads

Comment: @Slade what else you did with it because its not working for me :/

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem you can use this code below instead

[DisableRequestSizeLimit]